# UIScrollView velocity, number of iterations per second?

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

I'm trying to understand the velocity returned from my UIScrollView. From the delegate function:

```
func scrollViewWillEndDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, withVelocity velocity: CGPoint, targetContentOffset: UnsafeMutablePointer<CGPoint>) {
    }
```

I have observed the velocities. e.g. `-0.4`, `1.34`, `1.7` etc. I read somewhere this is `pts` travelled per second however this seems much to small. I also read that actually this is `pts` travelled per *iteration*. My question is, on average how many iterations are there per second? How can I translate this into a velocity I can actually use?

Comment: From `UIScrollView.h`: "velocity is in points/millisecond"

Answer (score 0):

In the documentation:

> **velocity** The velocity of the scroll view (in points) at the moment the touch was released.

In the UIScrollView.h file:

> // called on finger up if the user dragged. velocity is in
>   points/millisecond. targetContentOffset may be changed to adjust where
>   the scroll view comes to rest

Since its in milliseconds, small values make sense. The negative value denotes the bouncing effect of the scrollview.